# make span's jump to new line if not all the text fits on the current line

Tags: javascript, html, css

If you had something like:

```html
<div>
  <span> first thing here </span>
  <span> second thing here </span>
  <span> third thing here </span>
</div>
```

And you wanted to put these on a line, but if the whole third span doesn't fit, instead of breaking it in half and having part of it on one line and part on the next, you want the whole span to drop to the next line.

How would you do this?  Would you need to use javascript to determine if there's enough space left?

Comment: `span{inline-block}`

Comment: `span {display: inline-block}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
div span:nth-child(3) {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span> first thing here first thing here first thing here </span>
    <span> second thing here second thing here </span>
    <span> third thing here lorem </span>
</div>
```

Comment: seems to fit the bill perfectly, downvote makes no sense

Comment: it wasn't me :-/